# What is the best practice for a Salesforce data migration of a large amounts of records (10000-30000) from a third party storage?

Tags: salesforce, data-migration, salesforce-service-cloud

We are currently trying to move an average of 1000-3000 quotes with each having roughly 10 quote lines a piece (10000-30000 records) on a daily basis.

We are currently utilizing REST calls to update these objects within Salesforce. However, with this magnitude of data, this would not be feasible to process on a daily basis.

We’re considering using Bulk API as this could work with the size of data we have, however there’s concerns with processing times of data this large. Bulk API only carries 60,000ms of processing time.

Is there another way (aside from Bulk API) we could efficiently migrate this amount of data on a daily basis?

A caveat here, none of these records are stored within Salesforce currently. We are having to make API calls to receive this data from a third party storage. Below is an example of the JSON objects when get from these API calls:

```
"data":{ 
"id":"f1b34d84-260d-4f41-b164-a53d5ffbb4e2", 
"idhId":"f1b34d84-260d-4f41-b164-a53d5ffbb4e2", 
"QuoteID":"37d364bc3adde81180d6000d3a14a2jx", 
"QuoteNumber":"JD181000ZLA", 
"QuoteVersion":"0", 
"DateCreatedUTC":"2018 
05 
14 
 
T14:02:41Z", 
"Project":"Builders", 
"DealerCustomerNumber":"057856", 
"QuoteStatus":"15", 
"DealerEndCustomerNumber":"057856", 
"QuoteType":"DealerQuote", 
"QuoteLine":[ 
{"QuoteID":"37d364bc-3add-e811-80d6-000d3a14a2fg", 
 "LineNumber":"1", 
 "QuoteLineID":"38d364bc3adde81180d6000d3a14a2cb", 
 "PricingGroup":"VBLDRSPD", 
 "QuantityQuoted":"3", 
 "NetPrice":"0", 
 "ListPrice":"0", 
 "GenericDescription":"Sliding Door", 
 "QuoteLineAttribute": 
[ 
{"AttributeName":"pr-line-mkt", 
                "AttributeValue":"BV", 
    "PickCode":"pick code value", 
    "idhId":"d43b2de2-0608-4001-8397-f10d1fedaa4a", 
    "id":"d43b2de2-0608-4001-8397-f10d1fedaa4a" 
}, 
{"AttributeName":"impact", 
    "AttributeValue":"", 
    "idhId":"9da3e8b7-0f6d-41e4-be9c-d6c45934ceda", 
    "id":"9da3e8b7-0f6d-41e4-be9c-d6c45934ceda" 
}, 
{"AttributeName":"fne", 
    "AttributeValue":"W", 
    "idhId":"c3ea1bef-4cf8-4b9e-b562-a54cf69f391f", 
    "id":"c3ea1bef-4cf8-4b9e-b562-a54cf69f391f" 
}, 
{"AttributeName":"fni", 
    "AttributeValue":"W", 
    "idhId":"5175ee7a-ac6c-40a1-8959-d448ea3c842e", 
    "id":"5175ee7a-ac6c-40a1-8959-d448ea3c842e" 
}, 
{"AttributeName":"grid", 
    "AttributeValue":"Z", 
        "idhId":"22a516b0-16f8-4865-85c0-65777423f36f", 
        "id":"22a516b0-16f8-4865-85c0-65777423f36f" 
} 
], 
"idhId":"fdf116a2-496c-4cd7-bcff-9a45ca6f26aa", 
"id":"fdf116a2-496c-4cd7-bcff-9a45ca6f26aa" 
       }], 
 "DealerNetPrice":"1987.752", 
 "SubmitterEmail":"johndoe@doorsandwindowscompany.com" 
},
```

Our current process uses 10,000ms (sometimes 15,000ms) and that’s only pulling in ~50 quotes with ~10 quote lines a piece (550 records).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing several data elements into the same payload? Say - as in using curl:

curl -X POST -d'{
"data" : {
...
},
"data" : {
...
}
}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://theurl.com